# Python shared queue - 2 different threads

Tags: python, flask, concurrency, queue

```
import time
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from multiprocessing import Process, Value

app = Flask(__name__)

class Queue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.items == []

    def enqueue(self, item):
        self.items.insert(0,item)

    def dequeue(self):
        return self.items.pop()

    def size(self):
        return len(self.items)

tasks = [
   {
      'id': 1,
      'title': u'Buy groceries',
      'description': u'Milk, Cheese, Pizza, Fruit, Tylenol',
      'done': False
   },
   {
      'id': 2,
      'title': u'Learn Python',
      'description': u'Need to find a good Python tutorial on the web',
      'done': False
   }
]

q = Queue()

@app.route('/todo/api/v1.0/tasks', methods=['GET'])
def get_tasks():

   q.enqueue('cat')
   print("Size: " + str(q.size()))

   return jsonify({'tasks': tasks})


def record_loop(loop_on):
   while True:
      if loop_on.value == True:
         print("loop running")

         q.enqueue('dog')
         print("Size: " + str(q.size()))

      time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
   recording_on = Value('b', True)
   p = Process(target=record_loop, args=(recording_on,))
   p.start()
   app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
   p.join()
```

I have a global class called queue. The queue's data is shared between 2 different functions, but its not working.

Why is the queue in the function 'get_tasks()' size always equal 1? I thought queues are thread safe and they can be shared between different processes?

Comment: The size is not always 1 for me.  It's incrementing every time `record_loop` runs.  What is the end goal?

Comment: Make a task queue that is shared between these two functions. They need to have access to the same queue. Why isn't it changing the size in the 'get_tasks()' function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create a new process, it copies the current environment and re-creates it in the new environment.  Once you create the process, those global variables are no longer shared.

However, the `multiprocessing` library has included ways to [communicate between processes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes)

You can still use a queue, but you'll have to use the multiprocessing [Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue) instead of your home-rolled one.  Under the hood, each process has its own `Queue` object, and they're simply piping information back and forth between the processes to sync the queue state.